# Hazelcast does not populate ReplicatedMap at node startup

Tags: java, distributed-computing, hazelcast

This is the code with ClusterStorage being our code which wraps `Hazelcast`.

```
    public ClusterStorage clusterStorage() {
        Config config = new Config();
        String mapName = "cluster-storage";
        ReplicatedMapConfig mapConfig = config.getReplicatedMapConfig(mapName);
        mapConfig.setInMemoryFormat(InMemoryFormat.BINARY);

        config.getGroupConfig()
                .setName("name")
                .setPassword("pass");

        HazelcastInstance instance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);

        return new ClusterStorage(instance.getReplicatedMap(mapName));
    }
```

When I change the map while both nodes are up the change is replicated but when I change the map on node n1 and then start the second node n2 the state from n1 is not replicated and n2 node has empty map.

I suppose this should work, right ? 
What might be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it. My findings:

The problem was combination of version 3.7.1 and 3.5.5 comming from dependency management in Maven's `pom.xml`. We were not aware that Spring Boot's imported dependency management also defines `hazelcast` artifact with different version which in turn might have caused imcompatible libraries to be on the class path.

Answer (score 0):

It's not guaranteed that both maps will be in sync:

> Lost or missing updates are neither tracked nor resent

http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.5/manual/html/replicatedmap.html